# Instead of writing a bunch of for loops how could I combine these arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I needed to make a specific set of combinations with 4 different arrays. I wrote for loops but I know I could write this better. I need everything to combine together at least once but I also need combinations where it combines 3 arrays and then just 2. For example at first it would be [{position:'QB'},{position:'QB, status: 'A'},{position:'QB, status: 'A', sort: 'NAME'} and eventually just {sort: 'NAME', sort_type: 'week', week: 1}, {sort: 'NAME', sort_type: 'week', week: 1}. The end result should be about 1500+ combinations. Any help?

```
var positions = ['QB', 'WR', 'RB', 'TE', 'K', 'DEF'];
var statuses = ['A', 'W', 'T'];
var sort = ['NAME','OR', 'AR', 'PTS'];
var week = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18];

var filters = [];
var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
    obj = {
        position: positions[i] // Starting with positions
    };
    filters.push(obj);

    for (var j = 0; j < statuses.length; j++){
        obj = {
            position: positions[i],
            status: statuses[j]   // Adding statuses to all possible positions
        };
        filters.push(obj);
        for (var k = 0; k < sort.length; k++){
            obj = {
                position: positions[i],
                status: statuses[j],
                sort: sort[k]   //Adding sort to all possible positions and statuses combinations
            };
            filters.push(obj);
            for (var l = 0; l < week.length; l++){
                obj = {
                    position: positions[i],
                    status: statuses[j],
                    sort: sort[k],
                    sort_type: "week",
                    sort_week: week[l]  //Adding weeks to all possible positions, statuses and sort combinations
                };
                filters.push(obj);
            }
        }
    }
    for (var m = 0; m < sort.length; m++){
        obj = {
            position: positions[i],
            sort: sort[m]  // Starting back again with positions and this time making all combinations with just sort and no statuses
        };
        filters.push(obj);
        for (var n = 0; n < week.length; n++){
            obj = {
                position: positions[i],
                sort: sort[m],
                sort_type: "week",
                sort_week: week[n]  //Adding weeks to all combinations possible with just position and sort.
            };
            filters.push(obj);
        }
    }

}
for (var a = 0; a < statuses.length; a++){
    obj = {
        status: statuses[a]  //Starting now with only statuses
    };
    filters.push(obj);
    for (var p = 0; p < sort.length; p++){
        obj = {
            status: statuses[a],  //Adding sort to statuses only
            sort: sort[p]
        };
        filters.push(obj);
        for (var q = 0; q < week.length; q++){
            obj = {
                status: statuses[a],
                sort: sort[p],
                sort_type: "week",
                sort_week: week[q]  //Adding week to all combinations possible with status and sort only
            };
            filters.push(obj);
        }
    }
}
for (var b = 0; b < sort.length; b++){
    obj = {
        sort: sort[b]  //Starting with sort only
    };
    filters.push(obj);
    for (var o = 0; o < week.length; o++){
        obj = {
            sort: sort[b],
            sort_type: "week",
            sort_week: week[o]  //Adding all weeks to sort only
        };
        filters.push(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here. What is your expected output?

Comment: One array with about 1500 different combinations. It would look like [{position: 'QB'},{position: 'QB',status: 'A'},] and so on. This solution works for me. I just know I can write this better.

Comment: Would each element of each adjacent array be concatenated to `"QB"`?

Comment: See [Get all possible options for a matrix in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244987/get-all-possible-options-for-a-matrix-in-javascript/)

Comment: @guest271314 At first. But eventually I also want all the combinations without the positions array. I think my code is clear if you follow the loops. I just know I can write this better with some type of library or ES6 or even recursion. I just am not knowledgable enough in algorithms or what not to create this.

Comment: What is issue with `javascript` at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 JavaScript has a history of struggling to form arrays or decompose them. Libraries like LoDash, Underscore and Async have all come from this. My question is, how in JavaScript, can I write this code better leveraging any JavaScript library or ES6 functionality? I added comments to my code to better explain what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach for variable length of parts an their length.

```js
function combine(array) {
    function c(part, index) {
        if (index === array.length) {
            result.push(part.join(' '));
            return;
        }
        c(part, index + 1);
        array[index].forEach(function (a) {
            c(part.concat(a), index + 1);
        });
    }

    var result = [];

    c([], 0);
    return result;
}

var result = combine([['QB', 'WR', 'RB', 'TE', 'K', 'DEF'], ['A', 'W', 'T'], ['NAME','OR', 'AR', 'PTS'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]);

console.log(result.length);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes. This is the type of stuff I am looking for. Holy cow 2520 combinations! I didn't even think of doing weeks alone either. Thanks!

Comment: Where is `""` at index `0` derived from?

Comment: it comes from no value from all. `c(part, index + 1);`

Comment: @NinaScholz Besides just removing it from the final array. What else could be done to avoid the no value " "?

Comment: @user1842315, you could use a check first, like `part.join() && result.push(part.join(' '));`.  what format do you need? the object structure?