# JS recursively print all possibilities of nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, nested

I have a nested object, consisting of arrays as some values, in various hierarchies. How do I recursively create in vanilla JS, an array of all possibilities of the object, with each array element iterated over the object & 'flattened'? For example, lets say our object is:

```
let object = { phone: { home: [1111111111, 9999999999], office: 3 }, name: [officialName, petName] }
```

Resultant array is:

```
resultArr = [
            { phone: { home: 1111111111, office: 3 }, name: 'petName' },
            { phone: { home: 1111111111, office: 3 }, name: 'officialName' },
            { phone: { home: 9999999999, office: 3 }, name: 'petName'},
            { phone: { home: 9999999999, office: 3 }, name: 'officialName'}
            ];
```

From what I understand, to be able to do this dynamically, I should create a recursive function. I am able to get all array elements 1 by 1, but when I 'flatten' that particular array in the iteration, the other array stays as it is, and I am unable to fix that part / think through. 
Here is my codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWNdXe

Comment: Can you include the code that you have tried to resolve inquiry at Question?

Comment: See [Get all possible options for a matrix in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244987/get-all-possible-options-for-a-matrix-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the link. Is it possible to create a generic function? The solution refers to keys specific to example provided.